# Вытащить подстроку из строки Firebird

Tags: sql, строки, select, firebird

Добрый день
Подскажите как зная первый и последний знак в подстроке вытащить ее значение. Пробую так, но после for не срабатывает.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING (STRG from (position ('№' IN STRG) +1) for (position ('от',STRG))) FROM NAME
```

Comment: Что значит "не срабатывает" ошибку выдает или просто не правильно символы считает. Там вообще в for количество символов должно быть. А количество - это _"позиция 'от' МИНУС позиция '№'"_

Answer (score 1):

После FOR указывается не позиция конца, а количество символов.

```
SUBSTRING (STRG from (position ('№' IN STRG) +1) for (position ('от',STRG) - position ('№' IN STRG)))
```